# 'System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<string,string>' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I am trying to populate ddlCustomerType from XML using JSON. I am having one method which gives me key and value.

**`var listCustomerType = GlobalBind.GetXMLFullDetails("CustomerType", GlobalConstString.COMMON_SETTING_XML);`**

My problem is I am able to view data inside in Quickwatch but when I am trying to fetch its showing the following error:

**`CS0122:` '`System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<string,string>' is inaccessible due to its protection level`**

[Here you can check the image for same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxByC.png)

Can any body tell me how I can fetch records?

Comment: I found that class declared with `internal sealed class Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<K, V>`, so is `listCustomerType` a Sharepoint-related list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple. I don't know why I fall for getting data from  Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView. Funny...isn't it?

I fetch the details in dictionary like follow:

`Dictionary<string, string> listCustomerDetails = GlobalBind.GetXMLFullDetails("CustomerType", GlobalConstString.COMMON_SETTING_XML);`

and then I used a loop to fetch the key and value like following:

```
        foreach (var customer in listCustomerDetails)
        {
            ListItem ls = new ListItem();
            ls.Text = customer.Value;
            ls.Value = customer.Key;
            listItem.Add(ls);
        }
```

Thank you all for help.

Comment: So if your question had actually detailed the line of code that was throwing the error we probably could have helped you sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView then you cant. It is an internal object not meant for pubic use [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/debugview.cs,6c6d309fcd690dda,references) is the source where you can see its marked [internal sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619185/what-is-an-internal-sealed-class-in-c).

If you post a question about what you are trying to achieve maybe we can direct you to a more suitable solution.

Comment: thank you for quick response. I got the point but can you tell me how I can find the solution? I am getting details in variable but how I fetch value and key from that. I tried to receive it in List<string> but then I only got the name and not the value.