# Type.GetProperties Method Returns a PropertyInfo[] But PropertyInfo is Abstract

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

In the documentation for C# the GetProperties method of the Type class returns an array of Property Infos: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]. You can see this in the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-8.0

However, the PropertyInfo class is marked as abstract in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-8.0

Wondering how this is possible since abstract classes cannot be instantiated in c#. Would this be a typo in the documentation or is it returning something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that `PropertyInfo` is abstract. The thing is, `GetProperties()` actually returns [`RuntimePropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimePropertyInfo.cs) (a child class of `PropertyInfo`), which is not abstract. It is [`internal sealed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4619185/5623232) so you still can't instantiate it, but the runtime can.

```
foreach (var p in typeof(Exception).GetProperties())
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} - {p.GetType().FullName} - {p.GetType().IsAbstract}");
```

Comment: Interesting. Guess the documentation is still correct where GetProperties returns a PropertyInfo because a RuntimePropertyInfo is still a PropertyInfo

Comment: It's pretty much very similar to returning an interface, e.g. `public IAnimal GetPet() { return new Dog(); }`. And since C# 8.0, the line between interfaces and abstract classes has become [more blurry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)